# Retrieval of values from one node to another node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Structure in which I have different nodes such as `match_Points` and `myTeam`. Now what I want to do is to copy the value from `match_points` to the node in `myTeam`.

How can I do this task in a better way? This task is described with the help of a snapshot which is attached here which will clear my question. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDxHR.jpg)

Comment: First of all it is unclear, what is this for, android, web and what language are you using, JavaScript, java, Kotlin or any else. Please clarify these details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your question is whether there is any specific API to perform "copy" operations. And the short answer is: no.

But what is unclear from your question is whether you have considered [cloud functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to do your heavy lifting? It will remove the responsibility from your application to keep data duplication up to date.

So you could create a cloud function like this to copy the player score to the team every time it changes

```
export const copyMatchPointsToTeamScore = functions.database.ref('match_points/{match}/{player}/points').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const match = context.params.match;
    const player = context.params.player;
    const pointsBefore = change.before.val();
    const pointsAfter = change.after.val();
    const deltaScore = pointsAfter - pointsBefore;

    const myTeamId = 'SDFGSFDGxcz'; // Get your team ID from somewhere
    return admin.database().ref(`myteam/${myTeamId}/${match}/${player}/points`).transaction(trxPoints => {
        return typeof trxPoints === 'number' ? trxPoints + deltaScore : trxPoints;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding value into an object first then set value using that object? I think that is the only way you can copy the data inside the child node with multiple sub-nodes to another place.